# JavaFX LineChart Hover Values

Tags: javafx-2

I am in the process of creating a line chart in JavaFX. All is good currently and it successfully creates the chart with the data I need from a database stored procedure. Anyway what I require if possible is for every data point on the LineChart to have a mouse hover event on it which states the value behind the specific point, for example £150,000. I have seen examples of this been done on PieCharts where it shows the % value on hover but I cannot find examples anywhere for LineCharts, can this even be done?

Can anyone point me in the right direction if possible?

Code so far:

```
private static final String MINIMIZED = "MINIMIZED";
private static final String MAXIMIZED = "MAXIMIZED";
private static String chartState = MINIMIZED;
// 12 Month Sales Chart
XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();

public void getDeltaData() {

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        //Get all records from table
        String SQL = "";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //Create the result set from query execution.
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {

            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(rs.getString(1),
                    Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(7))));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(rs.getString(1),
                    Double.parseDouble(rs.getString(8))));

        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    yearChart = createChart();
}

    protected LineChart<String, Number> createChart() {
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    // setup chart
    series.setName("Target");
    series2.setName("Actual");
    xAxis.setLabel("Period");
    yAxis.setLabel("£");

    yearChart.getData().add(series);
    yearChart.getData().add(series2);

    yearChart.setCreateSymbols(false);

    return yearChart;
}
```

**Answer provided by jewelsea is a perfect solution to this problem.**

Thank you, jewelsea.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [XYChart.Data.setNode(hoverPane)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#setNode%28javafx.scene.Node%29) to display a custom node for each data point.  Make the hoverNode a container like a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html).  Add mouse event listeners so that you know when the mouse [enters](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseEntered%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) and [leaves](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseExited%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) the node.  On enter, place a [Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) for the value inside the hoverPane.  On exit, remove the label from the hoverPane.

There is some [example code](https://gist.github.com/4681797) to demonstrate this technique.

Output of the sample code is shown with the cursor hovered over the 22 node.

[image: hoverednode]

Comment: Thank you so much for this I would never of come close to achieving that. There is one final but minor issue. How do you set the hover to always be at the front? Some of my values are 6 figure numbers and they hide behind the next node which is quite annoying - see http://i.imgur.com/oZgNMNH.png

Comment: To ensure that the hovered node is always the top node, just call [toFront](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#toFront%28%29) when the mouse enters the node.  I updated the sample code to include this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was almost there but figured label.toFront() would cut it instead of just toFront(). Thanks once again for all your help it is much appreciated :)

Comment: toFront() means that hoverNode would inf front of his parent correct? Not infront of the wholechart. If you try to add something more complicated (a bigger container in size) then you probably will get out of bounds.

Comment: How can be avoided the cases on which the hover is on the corner of the chart and the label is only partially visible? It seems that the label is only draw inside the chart area and I need it to be replaced if part of it is outside, or to send it to the front of all even outside of the chart. Any solutions? @jewelsea

Comment: @Drubio If you are seeing the larger hovered nodes being partially visible, then there is probably some clip being applied in the chart implementation code.  Perhaps review the chart code in the JavaFX source, searching for the clip and see if you can determine an appropriate workaround for your case.  I don't want to expand this answer to account for such cases here.  I suggest you ask a new question and reference this one in it.

Answer (score 6):

**Using Tooltip:**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication250 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        Random rand = new Random();

        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> data = new TreeMap();
        //Create Chart data
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            data.put(rand.nextInt(51), rand.nextInt(51));
        }
        Set set = data.entrySet();

        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " - " + me.getValue());
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(me.getKey(), me.getValue()));//Add data to series
        }

        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        //loop through data and add tooltip
        //THIS MUST BE DONE AFTER ADDING THE DATA TO THE CHART!
        for (Data<Number, Number> entry : series.getData()) {                
            System.out.println("Entered!");
            Tooltip t = new Tooltip(entry.getYValue().toString());
            Tooltip.install(entry.getNode(), t);
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```