# JavaFX scene buildler charts, is there any easy way to add the ability to zoom into section chart

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I just went through a tutorial for scene builder and was able to build a stacked bar chart like I wanted. Is there any easy to add the ability to zoom into certain sections of the chart and only display the selected data??

Also is there any way to add a tooltip ability so that you can select a data point and it will display x,y coordinate or preferably be able to access some object data that you can attach to points.

Thanks you so much. I am new to JavaFX,scenebuilder and I havent' found much information about the charts.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.  The part of your question related to displaying a visual representation of object values at data points is demonstrated in: [JavaFX LineChart Hover Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615590/javafx-linechart-hover-values).  Zoom on selection is demonstrated in [this ZoomableLineChart example by james-d](https://gist.github.com/james-d/7252698).