# How display point values on LineChart Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, jfreechart

How display in all points values on Line Chart Java/JavaFX:

[image]

Comment: That just looks like a standard picture of a JavaFX `LineChart`. What are you actually asking?

Comment: I need display values betwenn [Y/X] points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question talks about showing the values on hoover [JavaFX LineChart Hover Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615590/javafx-linechart-hover-values)

You can likey adapt that solution to show the values all of the time.

Here is the example code refrenced there https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4681797

This code is untested but I would start by using the example with this modification

```
 HoveredThresholdNode(int priorValue, int value) {
      setPrefSize(15, 15);

      final Label label = createDataThresholdLabel(priorValue, value);
      getChildren().setAll(label);
      toFront();

    }
```

From there you can start to pull away the parts you dont need.

Comment: Use the supplied code, but instead of setOnMouseEnetered, just put that code in the constructor.

Comment: Is there another way?