# Setting tooltips on JavaFX line chart node

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, tooltip

I'm trying to add tooltips to the different nodes on a JavaFX line chart. My chart has two different series; each series has multiple data points. Each data point relates to an object. I need to access the datapoint's associated  object in order to add information to its tooltip.

From what I understand, the tooltips must be installed after the data has been added to the chart. I have created a HashMap that tracks the added data points against the relevant  object so I can retrieve the object after the data points are added to the chart.

The following is an example of how I add data to a series:

```
dataToAdd = new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(count), timeSpent);
addedData.put(dataToAdd, object); // Store a reference in a HashMap<XYChart.Data, DataObject>
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(count), timeSpent));
```

After running `lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2);` I loop through the chart's series and each series respective `XYChart.Data`. I then try to match this data with the data in my `HashMap` so I'm able to pull out the `Question` which contains data I want to provide to the tooltip. The following is a code snippet demonstrating this:

```
for (XYChart.Series<String, Number> s : lineChart.getData()) {
    for (XYChart.Data<String, Number> d : s.getData()) {
        // This if statement never evaluates to true
        if (addedData.containsKey(d)) {
            Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
            tooltip.setText("Difficulty: " + addedData.get(d).difficulty.toString());
            Tooltip.install(d.getNode(), tooltip);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why I'm unable to match the value against my Hashmap. I have tried all sorts of things, such as comparing against the `XY.Data.getNode()` method but this does not provide any matches either. I have confirmed that my HashMap is being populated with references to XY.Data objects. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: As Sedrick pointed out, I was adding a `new` instance of an XYChart.Data object, rather than providing a reference to the object I was adding to the HashMap, don't know how I missed this!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX LineChart Hover Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615590/javafx-linechart-hover-values)

Comment: Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @Sedrick but the answers to that question don't really help me. I don't think I require the listeners mentioned in that post, and even if I were to set them, I would not be able to retrieve the `Question` data associated with the data point. If I loop through all the `XY.Data` objects and install a tooltip with some hardcoded text, it display just fine. My question more relates to storing and then retrieving the `XY.Data` from a HashMap so I can display the data correlated by the `XY.Data` key in the HashMap.

Comment: Follow the second link I posted. I might be able to give more specific help after that.

Comment: Also, If you don't need the listener, just use the code inside of it.

Comment: You are right. the `mouseEntered` listener is not needed. I am updating the linked code.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, your problem is

```
listeningSeries.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(listeningQuestionCount), timeSpent));
```

with attention on

```
new XYChart.Data(Integer.toString(listeningQuestionCount), timeSpent)
```

This code should be

```
listeningSeries.getData().add(dataToAdd);
```

In your first case, you have this. In the rest, you don't. I personally would get rid of the `HashMap` and use the `setExtraValue()` like in the example below.

I am not sure if I am on the right track with your question, but one thing you can do is use `setExtraValue()` to add associated data to the node. That way you would not have to rely on the `HashMap`. The code below demos how to add extra data using setExtraValue()`.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication250 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("Line Chart Sample");
        //defining the axes
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        Random rand = new Random();

        Map<Integer, Integer> data = new TreeMap();
        //Create Chart data
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            data.put(rand.nextInt(51), rand.nextInt(51));
        }
        Set set = data.entrySet();

        //When you create the data points for the series, go ahead and add any assoicated data to the data point.
        int counter = 1;
        Iterator i = set.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) i.next();
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " - " + me.getValue());
            XYChart.Data tempData = new XYChart.Data(me.getKey(), me.getValue());
            tempData.setExtraValue("I am data point " + counter++);
            series.getData().add(tempData);//Add data to series
        }



        lineChart.getData().add(series);

        //loop through data and add tooltip
        //THIS MUST BE DONE AFTER ADDING THE DATA TO THE CHART!
        for (Data<Number, Number> entry : series.getData()) {
            System.out.println("Entered!");
            Tooltip t = new Tooltip(entry.getExtraValue().toString());
            Tooltip.install(entry.getNode(), t);
        }



        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sedrick. Unfortunately I have already tried this method but `getExtraValue` returns null for me. I have just created an MVCE though and am about to add it to my question.

Comment: Hi Sedrick, I've just read your edited answer and you are right, I was creating a new instance of `XY.Data` instead of referencing the one in the HashMap. I can't believe I missed this, had spent the entire day programmaing and was exhausted. I will follow your advice and take advantage of the `setExtraValue()` method. Thank you so much for your help.